What is the format / notation / units of price and liquidity data for tick entity in uniswap API?
I am pulling liquidity pool data from the uniswap API and I don't recognize the format or notation of the numbers that are being generated. Here is the code for ETH/USDT on uniswap v3:
import requests

query = """
{
  pool(id: "0x11b815efb8f581194ae79006d24e0d814b7697f6") { 
    ticks(first: 1000) {
      tickIdx
      price0
    }
  }
}
"""
url = "https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3"
response = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
response.json()

If you run this code you will see Price0 is a variety of extremely tiny numbers and extremely large numbers, none of which are close to the current price of ETH / USDT (around 3850 at time of writing).
I thought it was Q64.96 notation at first but it can't be, because some of the numbers are tiny? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding the notation.

This foxed me also, couldn't find any reference in documentation either, may be better if you asked in specific crypto focused ... (or someone more knowledgeable here will respond )
executing the following on the website - (all pools involved), so there is variance in the units that appear pool dependant...
https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3/graphql ...
query MyQuery {
    ticks (first : 20 ) {
      tickIdx
      price1
      price0
      volumeUSD
      tickIdx
      untrackedVolumeUSD
      volumeToken0
      volumeToken1
      poolAddress
      collectedFeesUSD
      collectedFeesToken0
      collectedFeesToken1
      liquidityNet
      liquidityGross
      feesUSD
    }
  }

#rendered
{
  "data": {
    "ticks": [
      {
        "tickIdx": "0",
        "price1": "1",
        "price0": "1",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0000d36ab86d213c14d93cd5ae78615a20596505",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-186000",
        "price1": "119529057.885128856603058433589305",
        "price0": "0.000000008366166501212040940232435062033917",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0000d36ab86d213c14d93cd5ae78615a20596505",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "0",
        "price1": "1",
        "price0": "1",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0001fcbba8eb491c3ccfeddc5a5caba1a98c4c28",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "-303015134493562686441",
        "liquidityGross": "303015134493562686441",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-92200",
        "price1": "10092.4109643974265827709388466852",
        "price0": "0.00009908435194797931978062497387592268",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0001fcbba8eb491c3ccfeddc5a5caba1a98c4c28",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "303015134493562686441",
        "liquidityGross": "303015134493562686441",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-201720",
        "price1": "575639104.2868453534828230549818432",
        "price0": "0.000000001737199562282850710376288478069214",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-203520",
        "price1": "689158928.499298238367274072392452",
        "price0": "0.000000001451044104119182556712190965176553",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-203760",
        "price1": "705897970.9281006185365396189270598",
        "price0": "0.000000001416635322928071149644681114672084",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-204060",
        "price1": "727394673.631354468061895657019627",
        "price0": "0.00000000137476948381780786540965092516788",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-205380",
        "price1": "830030635.6163292305186493026914019",
        "price0": "0.000000001204774808411092042866271440063804",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      },
      {
        "tickIdx": "-205440",
        "price1": "835025539.4164465384291875238248749",
        "price0": "0.000000001197568161446708619330637994010115",
        "volumeUSD": "0",
        "untrackedVolumeUSD": "0",
        "volumeToken0": "0",
        "volumeToken1": "0",
        "poolAddress": "0x0002e63328169d7feea121f1e32e4f620abf0352",
        "collectedFeesUSD": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken0": "0",
        "collectedFeesToken1": "0",
        "liquidityNet": "0",
        "liquidityGross": "0",
        "feesUSD": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}

